# How to show "AxesLabel" when "Frame -> True"

Tags: plotting

I'm using Mathematica 9.0.1, and using "LogLinearPlot" function. My problem is when I enable the "Frame", and set "AxesLabel", the labels won't be shown. If I disable the "Frame", the labels are shown? How can I show labels with frame on?

Comment: With Frame-> True, you need  FrameLabel-> {"x","y"} to label the axes.

Comment: Well done, thanks,